# Picking the right graphic card (GTX 970)

Tags: graphics-card, gaming, hardware-rec

I was thinking of buying a new graphic card and wondered if anybody could help me out picking the right one.

Currently I have a computer with an i7-2600 3.40GHz processor, 12 GB RAM and an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 550 Ti graphic card, I wanted to try out ARK: Surival but the graphics were just too good.

So I was thinking of buying this GTX 970 graphic card, is it a good choice, are there any differences between ASUS, MSI, Gigabyte, etc? Because there seems to be a whole lot of companies producing this type of card.

I'm not entirely familiar with the graphic card business and how it works, but some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different brands are generally just the designs of the coolers around the graphics card which is designed by NVidia. They'll all be in a similar ballpark in terms of temperatures and performance. Some may be overclocked or superclocked or ___clocked, in which case they'll be slightly faster.

Comment: Thanks, that's super great. But do you think I'm going with a good card here? Thanks!

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. Google 'ARK: Survival benchmarks' and see which graphics card perform ideally at the quality & resolution you want.

Comment: Okay, brilliant, I'll have a go. Thanks for all the help.